# How to combine consecutive two rows in a sql server as single row

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a data like this

**I have a data in database  which gives a table result looking like this:**

```
[Date]          [Type]  TC1   TC2    TC3
..........................................
'2014-11-01'    T       1     2      3
'2014-11-01'    T       4     5      6
'2014-11-02'    T       10    2      3
'2014-11-02'    T       4     5      6
'2014-11-03'    T       1     2      3
'2014-11-04'    T       4     5      6
```

**I want to make it look like this:**

```
  [Type]  TC1   TC2    TC3
............................................
    T     5      7     9
    T     14     7     9
    T     5      7     9
```

That means i want to combine data for consecutive  days it may be 2 rows or more than two rows, please help me on that.

Comment: try looking for GroupBy , Sum in TSQL

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2012+ then I think you should have a look at LAG http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Comment: if you will add the consecutive days, i think you will get only one record right? because 1, 2, 3, 4 are consecutive

Comment: Do you have holes in your dates sequence? If yes what happen when there is an hole between I.E. _2014-11-05_ and _2014-11-09_? Do you want to merge the two records or they should stay separated?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Is there some logical grouping that you can apply?  Grouping every two rows seems arbitrary.  What would you order by?

Comment: Based on your sample output, it looks to me as though you don't want *consecutive* days -- you want to group values that share the *same* date.  If so, @Bhavash has answered your question.  If not, we need a better example.  But either way, as posted, your question is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following:

```
declare @table table(Date datetime,Type char(1),TC1 int,TC2 int,TC3 int)

insert into @table(Date,Type,TC1,TC2,TC3)
select '2014-11-01','T',1, 2,3
union all
select '2014-11-01','T',4, 5,6
union all
select '2014-11-02','T',10,2,3
union all
select '2014-11-02','T',4, 5,6
union all
select '2014-11-03','T',1, 2,3
union all
select '2014-11-04','T',4, 5,6

;with RowNumber(Date,Type,TC1,TC2,TC3,Number)
as
(select Date,Type,TC1,TC2,TC3,row_number() over (order by Date) 
 from @table)
 select convert(varchar(12),r1.Date,113) as Date,r1.Type,r1.TC1+r2.TC1 as TC1,r1.TC2+r2.TC2 as TC2,r1.TC3+r2.TC3 as TC3
 from RowNumber r1
 inner join RowNumber r2 on r2.Number=r1.Number+1 and r1.Number % 2=1
```

result is

```
Date    Type    TC1 TC2 TC3
01 Nov 2014     T   5   7   9
02 Nov 2014     T   14  7   9
03 Nov 2014     T   5   7   9
```

hope this will help you

Comment: I don't think this is what he wants - it needs to group & sum CONSECUTIVE days

Comment: @markpsmith actually I think what he wants is to add consecutive RECORDS

Comment: @markpsmith i didn't get his question is this way, because if he will group the consecutive days, at the end he will get only 1 record because 1,2,3,4 are consecutive

Comment: @HadiHassan - I think he wants to sum the results from 01 + 02, then  02 + 03, and so on. That's what I see from looking at the totals in the example he's given, I think the wording is a bit unclear.

Comment: @markpsmith i just want to combine consecutive two rows as one row for example if table contains 30 records the resultant will be 15 like that

Comment: @Muralikrishna ok i got your question, i will edit the answer, just   i will build a sample code for you

Comment: @HadiHassan thanks for your response i will look into that and check weather it is suited my scenario or not :)

Comment: @HadiHassan is same code is applicable for adding 3 consecutive rows..?

Comment: @Muralikrishna to build a generic solution for adding N-consecutive rows, you might need to build a stored procedure with a cursor and taking two pointers one for current row and second for row-n and you will sum all rows satisfying the rule ( number between row-n and row), hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Following query will help you:

```
SELECT [Type], TC1, TC2, TC3 
FROM ( 
        select [Date],[Type], sum(TC1) as TC1,sum(TC2) as TC2, sum(TC3) as TC3 
        FROM YourTable group by
        [Date],[Type] 
     ) AS Tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, writing contorted SQL code is the wrong way to approach this problem. Take a look at the various SQL answers given. Can you look at them and immediately have an intuitive sense of what they are trying to do? How would you react looking at that code when you return to it 6 months down the line?

Now ask yourself how would you generate this output if you were to do the consecutive record grouping on the front end, in C#? Isn't that straightforward? You wouldn't even need to post a question like that on stackoverflow would you? When you revisited that code in 6 months, don't you think you'd have a better chance of understanding it?

Make a simple sql call to get the records from the database, and then just step through them with a foreach loop in C# and process your results there. It'll give you more maintainable code.